# Question about concept: In the expansion of $(1+x)^n$,the coefficients of terms equidistant from the beginning and the end are equal.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, binomial-theorem

**The concept:**

In the expansion of $(1+x)^n$,the coefficients of terms equidistant from the beginning and the end are equal.

The coefficient of the $(r+1)^{th}$ term from the beginning is $^nC_r$. The $(r+1)^{th}$ term from the end has $n+1-(r+1)$, or $n-r$ terms before it; therefore counting from the beginning it is the $(n-r+1)^{th}$ term, and its coefficient is $^nC_{n-r}$, which is equal to $^nC_r$.

**My question:**

$(x+y)^6=x^6+6x^5y+15x^4y^2+20x^3y^3+15x^2y^4+6xy^5+y^6$

Using the concept, let's take $r=2$. So the $(2+1)^{th}$, or third term, has a coefficient $^6C_2$ counting from the beginning. The third term has $6+1-(2+1)=4$ terms before it counting from the end. Up to this point I fully understand.

Now I don't understand where this $(n-r+1)^{th}$ came from. Plugging in values checks out, because in my example $(6-2+1)=5$, and indeed the fifth term has the same coefficient as the third term. And obviously  $^nC_{n-r}=^nC_r$.But again why $(n-r+1)$? How is this derived?

Comment: Note that $(x+y)^6=(y+x)^6$.

Answer (score 0):

Notice that there are $n + 1$ terms in the expansion of $(x + y)^n$. If we list them in order, then we get:

|  |  |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | $x^n$ |
| 2 | $x^{n-1} y$ |
| 3 | $x^{n-2} y^2$ |
| ... | ... |
| $n-1$ | $x^2 y^{n-2}$ |
| $n$ | $x y^{n-1}$ |
| $n+1$ | $y^n$ |

Notice that the $r+1$-th term is of the form $x^{n-r} y^r$. And by the symmetry of the expansion, the $r+1$-th term from the end will then be the term that's $x^r y^{n-r}$. But then since $x^r y^{n-r} = x^{n-(n-r)} y^{(n-r)}$, that term must be the $(n-r)+1$-th term from the top.